# Access pytest fixture params with class scope while ordering parametrized tests

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

[image]For my selenium testing using pytest, I have below logic in the conftest.py file

```
    import pytest
    from selenium import webdriver
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
    
    @pytest.fixture(params=["Chrome","Firefox"],scope='class')
    def oneTimeSetup1(request):
        if request.param == "Chrome":
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        if request.param == "Firefox":
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
    
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("https://courses.letskodeit.com/practice")
    
        if request.cls is not None:
            request.cls.driver = driver
        print("the velue of param is " + request.param)

    
        yield driver
        driver.quit()
```

my test structure is

```
dir tests
--conftest.py
--test_one.py
----TestClassOne
------test_one
------test_two
```

when I collect the test, I can see below

```
<Package tests>
  <Module test_one.py>
    <Class TestClassOne>
        <Function test_one[Chrome]>
        <Function test_one[Firefox]>
        <Function test_two[Chrome]>
        <Function test_two[Firefox]>
```

Since the scope of oneTimeSetup1 fixture is class, I am not sure why each test function is running with new browser session.

Can we have a single Chrome browser session that will execute both my test_one & test_two and then
the same for firefox.

```
import pytest
from pages.page1 import Page1


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetup1")
class TestClassOne():

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classObject(self):
        self.page = Page1(self.driver)

    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_one(self):
        self.page.methodA()
        print("This is Test One")

    @pytest.mark.run(order=2)
    def test_two(self):
        self.page.methodC()
        print("This is Test Two")
```

Comment: Yes, I can see the browser is getting invoked in total 4 times. Shouldn't it call twice? Once with the browser = Chrome & browser = Firefox??

Comment: I add print("the velue of param is " + request.param) in the oneTimeSetup1. I have attached the CLI screenshot. For each of the test functions, a new browser session is getting invoked.

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce the problem now - it has to do with `pytest-ordering` (I didn't have installed it in my first try). It seems to break the scope. As I happen to maintain `pytest-order`, the successor of `pytest-ordering` (which is no longer maintained), I will write a bug for this. Try to remove the `run` marks for now and check if it still happens.

Comment: Thanks, Works like a charm after removing the @pytest.mark.run. Is there any other way to maintain the order of tests.? I hope they fix this issue in the next pytest-order release.

Comment: The problem is with parametrized tests here - ordering the tests will put the parametrized tests together, while the class scope would do the opposite. I will think about this... As I wrote, I maintain `pytest-order`, so "they" would be me in this case. I will see what I can do, though I'm a bit unclear yet, because class-scoped parametrization and ordering somewhat contradict each other here.

Comment: apologies...kudos to you for doing such a great work by creating plugins. It really makes life easy for testers like me. The reason I am using parameterize is to achieve parallel cross-browser testing. I am using the pytest-xdist plugin for it and then run my tests using pytest -s -v tests -n 2 --dist loadfile.  Is there any other way to achieve parallel cross-browser testing?

Comment: There may be other ways, but your way should work anyway, so I will try to fix this. I will see if I can get something done over the weekend (and it wasn't me BTW who wrote the plugin in the first place, I forked it from the unmaintained `pytest-ordering` to fix some issues and add some features).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem comes from the ordering via the `pytest-ordering` plugin. This is actually expected behavior (and not a bug, as I wrote initially), because the tests are explicitely ordered, and this ordering is done after any initial ordering due to the fixture usage.

There is a possibility to change this behavior, if using [pytest-order](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/) (a fork of [pytest-ordering](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-ordering/), which is no longer maintained) with the option [--indulgent-ordering](https://pytest-dev.github.io/pytest-order/stable/configuration.html#indulgent-ordering). This changes the sequence of the ordering, so that the tests are first ordered by the plugin, and afterwards by the fixture. Note that you have to change the order marker from `run` to `order` in this case:

```py
...
    @pytest.mark.run(order=2)
    def test_one(self):
        self.page.methodA()
        print("This is Test One")

    @pytest.mark.order(1)
    def test_two(self):
        self.page.methodC()
        print("This is Test Two")
```

(I changed the order to show that the ordering has any effect). If run this without an option, you will get (as seen in the original question):

```
$ python -m pytest --collect-only
<Package tests>
  <Module test_one.py>
    <Class TestClassOne>
        <Function test_two[Chrome]>
        <Function test_two[Firefox]>
        <Function test_one[Chrome]>
        <Function test_one[Firefox]>
```

With the `--indulgent-ordering` option, you get instead:

```
$ python -m pytest --collect-only --indulgent-ordering
<Package tests>
  <Module test_one.py>
    <Class TestClassOne>
        <Function test_two[Chrome]>
        <Function test_one[Chrome]>
        <Function test_two[Firefox]>
        <Function test_one[Firefox]>
```

which makes it possible for the fixture to properly work as a class-scoped fixture.

As usually, you can add the option to your `pytest.ini` if you want it to be effective for all tests:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --indulgent-ordering
```

*Disclaimer*:
I'm the author of `pytest-order`.